# nodejs server code inside view

Tags: node.js, express

I am building a website with nodejs & express.
I originally come from the .net world, building sites with MVC / Razor.

Is there a way to insert server side code into a view using nodejs/express ?
In my head i'm thinking of something similar to what I can do in a asp.net mvc view, like this :

```
<div class='user-info'>
    <%= Db.FetchUserById(1).Name %>
</div>
```

Comment: You should really ask yourself "Do I want to mix view with business logic"

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have A LOT of options. Check this list :
https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-templating

The one have heard of the most is Jade : http://jade-lang.com/ I think.

Comment: Don't overlook ejs (https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs), it's got a similar syntax to razor.

Answer (score 0):

[Mustache is what you are looking for.](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)

It works with Express aswell. Here is a quick guide on [how to push your objects to the view.](http://bitdrift.com/post/2376383378/using-mustache-templates-in-express)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ejs, I think it has similar syntax.

https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs

you can start building an express application with --ejs ( i.e express --ejs) to include it as  template engine.